# How to create tree like compound index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to indexing. Just read the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#Indexes-UsingDocumentsasKeys).

How do i create an compound index like below. I want to create an index on state name, inside that index, i want to create an index based on the population of that state.

```
                 state wise index
                       |
 ----------------------------------------------------
 |                    |                              |
pop<2000    pop>2000 & pop<5000    pop>5000 & pop<10000
```

*Question updated for @Derick :*

This is my mock data.

```
    {"pop" : 1000,"state" : "AL"}
    {"pop" : 1500,"state" : "AL"}

    {"pop" : 2500,"state" : "AL"}
    {"pop" : 3000,"state" : "AL"}

    {"pop" : 6000,"state" : "AL"}
    {"pop" : 8000,"state" : "CA"}
```

then,

```
db.simplezips.createIndex({state:1, pop:1});
db.simpezips.find({state:"AL", pop:{$gte:2500}}).explain();
```

give logs like below. Which is correct to my expectation.

```
    "n" : 3,
    "nscannedObjects" : 3,
    "nscanned" : 3,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
```

*Questions:*

1. What i want to know is, how mongodb bucketizes/indexes the documents
   based on population.
2. How do i customize that bucketization ? (as shown in the above
   diagram.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: @Philipp, by creating an index like said above, i can reduce the amount of rows to scan. For ex. if the query is state=="CA" and pop>3000 the above index will scan only the docs that fall in the middle and last bucket. But in the absence of an pop index as shown above, it has to scan all the documents under the state index.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control how MongoDB buckets its indices. And likely you don't need to. A simple index on the pop field is likely good enough.

But when you really want to try to get some extra performance by taking advantage of the fact that you only have three ranges you query for, you could add another field `sizeCategory` to each document which has a value of `1` when the pop is <2000, `2` when the pop is between 2000 and 5000 or `3` when the pop is larger than 5000. Create a non-unique index on that field and query for it.

Comment: Actually, an index with only 3 elements is not going to be much faster than a normal range query, so I doubt that this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just mean a compound index on state, pop? Then this works just fine:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { state: 1, pop: 1 } );
```

This index can be used for the following query groups:

- `find( { state: "TX", pop: { $lt : 2000 } } )`
- `find( { state: "TX", pop: { $gte: 2000, $lt: 5000 } } )`
- `find( { state: "TX" } ).sort( { pop: 1 } );`
- `find( { state: "TX", pop: { $gte: 2000, $lt: 5000 } } ).sort( { pop: -1 } )`

MongoDB doesn't use "buckets" for indexes, but b-trees which are good for range queries. You can not control this mechanism, but you don't have to either as b-trees are good enough and a solution where you add a specific field to store your "bucket number" in is not likely to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks @Derick for the answer. I have updated the question. Please read my updates in the question.